# Getting components from Xamarin using the VS 2015 "Get more components"

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

When trying to "Get more components" using VS 2015 and Xamarin.
The xamarin log in screen is displayed, when I log in I get the following error.
Does this mean the server is down. This prevents me from using the xamarin.mobile component.
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7TEo.png)

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/
Xamarin components now located in Nuget